# google cloud error "mount: you must specify the filesystem type"

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, mount, disk, gcloud

I have created a standard persistent disk on google cloud but I am not able to mount it, if fails with

> mount: you must specify the filesystem type

I have check that the disk was created correctly with "gcloud compute disks describe mydisk":

```
kind: compute#disk

sizeGb: '500'

status: READY

type: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/micro-spanner-xxx/zones/us-central1-c/diskTypes/pd-standard

zone: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/micro-spanner-xxx/zones/us-central1-c
```

A previous disk that I created in the same way can be mounted ok.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to format the disk before mounting it. Per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/persistent-disks#formatting), you can do the following:

```
$ sudo mkdir MOUNT_POINT
$ sudo /usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount -m "mkfs.ext4 -F" DISK_LOCATION MOUNT_POINT
```

The `/usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount` script exists on all standard Google Compute Engine VM images.

Comment: I'll try that thanks! I didnt recall doing this for my previous disk